GetObjectAcl throws exception for OCI bucket in Laravel 11
In Laravel 11 on PHP 8.3, when using an OCI bucket with the S3 compatible object storage URL, uploading and downloading files works fine, however moving files or copying files fails.
Debugging the AwsS3V3Adapter file reveals that the command execution for "GetObjectAcl" fails. I am using the administrator user of OCI with a "Customer secret key". Is this a permission issue within OCI or is the AWSS3 adapter simply not compatible with OCI Object Storage?
'oci' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => env('OCI_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret' => env('OCI_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region' => env('OCI_DEFAULT_REGION'),
    'bucket' => env('OCI_BUCKET'),
    'url' => env('OCI_URL') .  '/'.  env('OCI_BUCKET'),
    'endpoint' => env('OCI_URL'),
    'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', true),
    'throw' => true,
],

The customer secret key has been created after the following guide:
https://www.ateam-oracle.com/post/aws-s3-to-oci-access-best-practices
The custom filesystem provider is based on this stack overflow post:
https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/1799
It is worth mentioning that the up- and download works just fine without a custom provider and simply by configuring the .env AWS variables accordingly - the exception thrown remains the same.
I have tried to use the default s3 configuration with use_path_style_endpoint set to true.
Next I have tried to create a new service provider for OCI which results in the same exception.
I have tried with the default URL, the dedicated URL and the S3 compatible endpoint, only the last one seems to work at all, for the others even the upload fails (https://{namespace}.compat.objectstorage.{region}.oraclecloud.com)
I have also tried to add a VisibilityAdapter which didn't change the outcome.
Creating a new compartment policy did not help as well:
Allow group ObjectWriters to manage objects in compartment XXX
Allow service objectstorage-<region_identifier> to manage object-family in tenancy

For everybody having the same problem, Kennethheung explained the root cause of the problem here: https://www.reddit.com/r/oraclecloud/comments/1gpk8my/troubleshooting_bucket_policies_with_laravel/

https://github.com/patrickriemer/oci-adapter -> Started working on an OCI compatible filesystem adapter. A few methods working already. Any contributors are welcome :)
